# Manual firewall configuration with SuSEfirewall2

Tags: firewall

I have a Suse server and I want to configure its firewall settings by manually editing the SuSEfirewall2 file (located in /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2). My goal is to accept only specific services on specific ports coming from a specific IP in the internal (INT) network.

So far I have read the various online manuals for configuring that file, but none of them helps me. I have tried the following modifications:

```
FW_PROTECT_FROM_INT="yes"
...
FW_SERVICES_INT_TCP="<necessary services>"
...
FW_SERVICES_ACCEPT_INT="<internal IP>/<mask in CIDR notation>,<port>,<service>"
```

However, this does not seem to work. Is this the right way to achieve my goal? What other ways to do that are there? (by editing the SuSEfirewall2 file)

EDIT: I still don't know how to do it. In what other way (besides editing the configuration file) can I do it?